# Java glue server changes IP on bind

Tags: java

I am trying to bind a service URL but getting the following exception

code :

```
strHostName=inet[x].getHostAddress();
String url = "http://" + strHostName + ":" + strGluePort
                    + "/glue/BladeInventoryService.wsdl";
logger.info("url "+url);
IGBladeInventoryService objGlue = (IGBladeInventoryService) Registry
                    .bind(url, IGBladeInventoryService.class);
```

exception :

```
url http://192.168.3.42:8004/glue/BladeCommandService
electric.util.WrappedException: java.rmi.ConnectException: url = http://169.254.245.248:8004/glue/BladeCommandService
    at electric.proxy.handler.Proxy.getCompatibleException(Unknown Source)
    at electric.proxy.handler.Proxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at $Proxy12.executeCommandOnBlade(Unknown Source)
    at com.clearcube.glue.GBladeCommandService.executeCommandOnBlade(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you get this wsdl (behind the url: 'http://169.254.245.248:8004/glue/BladeInventoryService.wsdl') in your browser?

Comment: I was unable to replicate the scenario once I restarted the glue server ,every thing start working properly.. posted this here to make sure if this problem had a specific solution or exception handler

Comment: it had something to do with APIPA which issued a temporary IP address . this was picked up by the glue server . the IP resolved fine but the glue server kept using the 169 IP address .